# Automatic memory allocation occurs at compile time or at run time in C?

Tags: c, memory, scope, static, auto

If we talk about static memory allocation it is said to be allocated at compile time but actually compiler just handles this memory allocation and it is actually allocated at start of program only. For example the compiler may create a large `data` section in the compiled binary and when the program is loaded in memory, the address within the `data` segment of the program will be used as the location of the allocated memory.

If I talk about automatic memory allocation, it is allocated when the control enters a new scope. Now my doubt is whether in this case also compiler comes into picture and passes some virtual addresses into the compiled binary which later becomes the addresses of actual allocated memory during runtime or this memory is allocated only at run time without any role of compiler just like the way dynamic memory is allocated ?

What if I have some local variable like:

```
int a = 10;
```

Will it have a compile time allocation or run time allocation ?

Comment: The compiler can optimise away that variable (no memory allocation), use a register only for that variable (no memory allocation) or generate instructions to allocate space on the stack for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic allocation happens in run-time, though the nature of it is very system-specific. Automatic storage duration variables may end up in registers, on the stack or optimized away entirely.

In case they do end up on the stack, the compiler creates a local scope offset to the function where the variable is allocated. That is, the variable might be referred to as `SP + 8` or something similar, where SP is the stack pointer. Which in turn could hold any value when the function is entered - the compiler or machine code does not know or care about that, which is why stack overflows exist.

You might find this useful: [What gets allocated on the stack and the heap?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277536).

Comment: If i am getting it right, it means the compiler will create scope offsets but the actual allocation for them will be done at run time only ?

Comment: @LocalHost Yes, they get allocated either with specific push instructions or as part of a stack frame, depending on ISA and ABI.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are placed on the stack when they are stored in memory.

Typically, the total stack size requirement for a function is calculated at compile time.
Then, when entering a function, the stack pointer is adjusted down for the entire stack size of the function - the stack usually grows from a higher address towards a lower address.

Each local variable is assigned an address within the current stack frame, and they are typically accessed with memory access instructions that read or write memory with a given offset to the current stack pointer.

However, in optimized builds, local variables are often also kept in CPU registers (whenever there are enough registers available) and not necessarily stored in memory at all. The purpose of this is to avoid memory accesses in order to speed up the program. Register allocation (the compiler choosing which variables to store in registers and which register to use for which variable) depends on large amount of black magic the compiler does analysing the lifetime of the variable and how much it is used.